# Excel RAND incrementing numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, random-number-generator

I have two numbers in excel a min and max and I want to fill in a random number between those two numbers but it must increase each time

thinking something like

```
INT(RAND()+C3)
```

and c3 has a value of 1130 so I get a random number and then add the previous value to that number which gives me an increase in each number.

Comment: And what it your question?

Comment: that formula doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Use the
[RANDBETWEEN function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/randbetween-function-4cc7f0d1-87dc-4eb7-987f-a469ab381685).

Syntax : `RANDBETWEEN(bottom, top)`

To ensure it is increasing, I can see two approaches:

1. Use `RANDBETWEEN(last-value, top)`
   The risk here is that the series will hit the high numbers too soon,
   and stay stuck in that range.
2. For a series of N random numbers, divide the range into N equal segments,
   then use the RANDBETWEEN function for each segment, from the bottom
   segment to the top one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 and depending on what you are looking to accomplish you could use RANDARRAY and target the starting value on the results of the last number. The think to keep in mind is this is a dynamic formula and it will keep updating the results every time you make a change elsewhere or open the file.

[image]

Of course you can copy an paste the values to keep them. I arbitrarily added 200 to the top value based off the last results.

Comment: just wrap a `SORT` around the `RANDARRAY`, no need for the column C...

Answer (score 0):

If cell B21 has the minimum value，B33 has the maximum value, then you can enter the formula in B22, `=RAND()*($B$33-B21)+B21`, and then drag down.

Please note, press F9 will refresh the results.

[image]